# Migrating ASP.NET Membership Database to SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to migrate a database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure. The database that I am attempting to migrate includes the ASP.NET Membership database (http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/membership). This database works fine when I run it in my SQL Server 2008 database. However, when I try to authenticate a user against SQL Azure, I receive an error that says:

"Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again."

However, I'm not sure what to do. When I try to update the index on the aspnet_Applications table, I receive a foreign key problem. I am using the following in an attempt to migrate my non-clustered index to a clustered index:

```
ALTER TABLE aspnet_Applications
DROP CONSTRAINT PK__aspnet_A__SOMEID

ALTER TABLE aspnet_Applications
ADD CONSTRAINT PK__aspnet_A__SOMEID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ApplicationId)
```

Can someone please help me overcome this issue? Thank you!

Comment: upgrade your server to SQL DB V12 which support heaps, and it is much closer to SQL stand alone compared to V11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, try to use the [ASP.NET Universal Providers For SqlExpress 1.1](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers) (I wish they'd change the name as it is a bit of a misnomer).  This is the officially supported method of enabling the SQL membership, role and session providers across both SQL Azure and standalone SQL Server.

Here are a couple of other links for reference:

[Scott Hanselman - Introducing System.Web.Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)

[SQL Azure Team Blog - Using SQL Azure for Session State](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/04/10046103.aspx)

Comment: SQL Azure now supports heaps on V12 servers, so this should no longer be an issue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: second link now broken but the blog can be found here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-sql-azure-for-session-state/

Answer (score 5):

I had problems with the ASP.NET membership provider tables (non clustered indexes) and missing the `"WITH (NOLOCK)"` statement on the stored procedure `aspnet_Membership_GetNumberOfUsersOnline` etc.

The migration tool found here fixed the problems and exported the database to Azure.

**http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/**

It is a nice wizard that connects to your existing SQL Server and migrate the selected database to Azure.

Comment: This SQL Azure Migration Wizard made this so easy, and fixed all of the issues with aspnet_Membership seamlessly.  Great stuff.

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10 by downloading the v5.15.6 Release.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure is not the same as SQL Server because not all features are supported. There is a special SQL Azure Membership Script to create the database.

See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191/de

I hope this helps.

Greetings.

Comment: thanks, that really helped me where the chosen answer did not.

Comment: The Membership provider is deprecated therefore the script won't work any more. But there is a new Membership implementation. Take a look at this: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.de/2013_02_01_archive.html

Comment: @MUG4N link dead also.