# How do i run aspnet_regsql on sql azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, membership-provider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating ASP.NET Membership Database to SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140774/migrating-asp-net-membership-database-to-sql-azure)

How do I run aspnet_regsql on sql azure database? I made it work the hard way, by exporting all db objects over. However, I seriously believe that there's an easier way. Please help.

Comment: this shouldnt be a duplicate because what if you want to run this for another reason, eg creating the health monitoring tables?

Comment: It's not a duplicate - and all the answers are different

Comment: The answer for me was that I should be using asp.net identity 2 which doesn't require regsql to be run or the `<rolemanager>` to be set in web.config ... check out this intro: http://johnatten.com/2014/09/21/asp-net-identity-2-0-introduction-to-working-with-identity-2-0-and-web-api-2-2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run aspnet_regsql on sql azure database, the error occurs only because SQL Azure does not support the **USE** statement to switch database contexts when it executes commands against SQL Azure databases.

To work around this, Microsoft created a hotfix. The following steps show you how to use the tool that is provided by the hotfix.

1. Download the aspnet_regsqlazure.zip file from the [hotfix page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2006191).
2. Extract the contents of the file to a location on your local hard drive.
3. Open a command prompt and navigate to the directory where you extracted the files.

Use the following command line to execute the tool (substitute your server name, database name, logon, and password where appropriate).

```
aspnet_regsqlazure -s [your server name].database.windows.net -d [your database name] -u [your user name]@[your server name] -p [your password] -a mr
```

Comment: I get the following error from running this command. Execution failed: No operation was specified on the command line - wizard mode is not supported. Any idea why it says this?

Comment: When I click on your hotfix link to download InstallAspSchema.zip, it takes me to a "Connect Registration" page, then I get a sign-in page that says "Something went wrong and we can't sign you in right now. Please try again later."

Comment: The hotfix page link is not working anymore. If somebody needs the zip file, I have uploaded it right here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B140xl7AMvJIWFktTUExejVuMmM

Comment: Thank you Denis!

Comment: @DenisSoto now the second link is broken too

Comment: Oh sorry @user1, I can't find it any more :(

Answer (score 5):

Membership Provider generated by aspnet_regsql.exe is out dated.

Please use new [Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) which is Azure compatible.

### Update - 7/23/2015

Microsoft has new membership called [Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). Current version is 2 as of this writing.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, this is THE way to do it, the providers are excellent and are copied to your Azure DB at the click of a button. If anyone wants a complete end to end example let me know.