# Azure and Aspnet_regsql.exe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-sql-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating ASP.NET Membership Database to SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140774/migrating-asp-net-membership-database-to-sql-azure)

I recently published an MVC3 application to Microsoft Azure, and with a bit of help I was able to get my EF database working correctly.  However, I am running into an issue with the default roles and users that I used instead of creating my own tables for admin login etc.

I have found answers that require you to run Aspnet_regsql.exe which I did, but I receive the following error:

```
Setup failed.

Exception:
An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. 
The SQL error number is 40508 and the SqlException message is: USE statement
is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect
to a different Database.
```

I searched for this error and I saw that this does not work with Windows Azure.  It led me to this post which helps explain why and gives a solution: http://thinkfirstcodelater.com/blog/?p=637

It tells me to download the following files and run them. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2006191/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3539

The problem is, when I run the application that is in that folder, the command line comes up and disappears.  I cannot see what it says, only that it failed.  What can I do to solve this issue?

The original problem stems from this:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
```

Which is displayed when I attempt to log into my own website.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the version that has been adapted for SQL Azure because like the error already says, SQL Azure doesn't support the USE statement: 
[KB2006191 - Updated ASP.NET scripts for use with SQL Azure](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2006191/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3539)

**Note:** Duplicate of [How do i run aspnet_regsql on sql azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158478/how-do-i-run-aspnet-regsql-on-sql-azure)

Comment: I ran this, and it will not work.  Do I run it through Visual Studio?  It opens up the command prompt and then it disappears immediately.  Any idea why?

Comment: I cannot find the knowledge base article. It has been taken down.